# Issues with this website in responsive design

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design

Im changing this website currently to responsive design.
Everything works fine on my PC and also on online responsive checker.
But If I Access the site on my actual Iphone 5/7 or Ipad 2 the slider has huge
issues which switching to the next image.
The website is: http://gsa.taheri-create.com/
Could any of you please check it and advice me what could be wrong? 
I re-checked everything basically like 3x but couldnt find an issue.
On Responsinator.com etc it works well, just not on the actual devices....

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry I don't have iPhone and iPad devices. Can I repro the same issue in any browser.

Comment: that's the actual Problem, on Browsers it works fine, let me take a screenshot to show you what I am talking about. http://i.imgur.com/oqlcUQ8.png

Comment: In the slider, while the slider switches the image at first there comes a white image and then the actual image pops up. it should actually switch images smoothly as it does on browsers...

Comment: @kazaam00nix https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: I cannot find any issues on that either. but as I said, on the real device I see the problem.